# How to let matlab to control the parameters in adams(bushing force) in co-simulation adams/matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Thanks for reading.I would like to Co-Simulate a Multibody-System (generated in MSC Adams) with a Controller in Matlab.The aim of co-simulation is to  identification the parameters of Multibody-System.I try to let matlab to determine the parameters of Multibody-System and then change the parameters by results.
Here is the question.I have to use bushing force in Multibody-System,but adams don't allow me to  control the parameters of bushing force by State variables,but state variables are necessary for matlab to interact with adams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a way to slove this.The ADAMS_init array can change the value of design value,and design value can be used in bushing force.I try to write a matlab script to do this and I success.I hope this experience can help you.